# Checking work of C# String.Intern method through ProcessHacker

Tags: c#, memory-management, string-interning

I'm playing around with C# String.Intern method and have one questions. Suppose I have a program that reads a text file line by line and adds this lines to a list of strings. Let's assume that this file consists of thousands of lines of the same string. If the text file is big enough I can see that my program consumes decent amount of RAM. Then if I use String.Intern method when I add lines to my list, consumptions of memory drops significantly and this means that string interning works fine. Then I want to check how many strings my dotnet process has through ProcessHacker. But whether I use String.Intern or not ProcessHacker shows the same huge amount of duplicating string. I expect it would show only one instance of the string since I use String.Intern.

What do I miss?

[image]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.txt";

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    list.Add(line);
                    //list.Add(String.Intern(line));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Do a GC.Collect();GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();GC.Collect()* The *string*s have been generated before being interned.

Comment: "consumptions of memory drops significantly" - this probably means you have no idea what you are measuring and what you are looking for... Or you are not willing to properly spell out what you are measuring. There is no commonly agreed upon "memory consumption" term... There are a lot of different ways to measure different aspects of memory usage - like multiple variants of per-process memory usage, memory usage reported by GC,... I don't believe code shown here will change process level memory usage with/without interning for example as it had to allocate exactely the  same number of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Every `streamReader.ReadLine()` will always create a new string which will be garbage collected but until GC it will exist in memory. Your memory consumption can drop cause `String.Intern` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-5.0#returns) the system's reference to string, if it is interned; otherwise, a new reference to a string with the value of string and your `list` will consist from references to the same instance of string which was interned making the ones created by `streamReader.ReadLine()` available for GC.

```
var str = "Test"; // compile time constant will be interned by default
var str1 = new string(str.ToArray()); // simulate reading string
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1, string.Intern(str1))); // prints false
```

Comment: Why the number of allocated strings would be different with/without `Intern` call? There will be difference in alive objects, but I don't get why do you think there will be less allocations...

Comment: I see you point - make sense. Also OP has tiny sample "thousands of lines of the same string" - there is very unlikely even  Gen0 collection to happen...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov TBH has never worked with PorcessHacker, so maybe this question is not correct, removed it. Yes, it seems my assumption is not very valid, based on screenshot OP has only 6k of strings which are not that big.